# Loop IE to find url

Tags: vba

Im trying to write a vba script to loop through running IE and detect a text string in the url 'Itinerary'

Then to input 2 fields:
Code
Surname

Then click ok

After loading is complete to be visible

Thank you
Jay

Comment: What are we supposed to do with this ?

Comment: I didnt explain it properly.

Comment: Hi

Im trying to write a vba script to loop through a running Internet Explorer which is surpose to detect a text string in the url.

Comment: Can someone help with the script.

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through all open tabs in IE and return the URL to column A.
Then you can search for a string and return the address of the found cell. After that you can add the `Code` and `Surname` (whatever that is?) to that cell.
Use this http://vba-corner.livejournal.com/4623.html to figure out how to open the newly edited URL in IE.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetURLofOpenIETabs()
    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim objShell As Object, objAllWindows As Object
    Dim ow
    Dim rngSearch As Range

    i = 2

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objAllWindows = objShell.Windows
    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each ow In objAllWindows
        If (InStr(1, ow, "Internet Explorer", vbTextCompare)) Then
            mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) = ow.locationURL
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    Set rngSearch = Sheet1.Cells.Find("text to find")

    If rngSearch Is Nothing Then
    ' do nothing
    Else
        MsgBox rngSearch.Address
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What a nice reaction. Do you expect people to help you with that attitude? You should read the guidelines. And yes, it works. What error do you get?

Comment: Hi, thanks. Im trying to use it. But its working. Will try again. New to this forum.